# execute pipes command in android?

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

I want to display application logs.
On terminal I used this command: adb logcat -s brief *:V|grep "pid"
It's display My Application logs.

pid means application pid which is display in logcat table.

```
  public static String logProc()
{
     String value = "";
     try
     {
         String cmd[] = {"logcat","-s","brief","*:V","|","grep",
                 android.os.Process.myPid()+""};
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null, null);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         String line = reader.readLine();

         while (line != null)
         {
             value += line + "\n";
             line = reader.readLine();
         }
         p.waitFor();
     }
     catch (IOException e1)
     {
         e1.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @Deepali:problem is its not showing any output.Its' continuosly display following logs                                            06-14 15:16:43.104: I/dalvikvm-heap(591): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.535MB for 881344-byte allocation
06-14 15:16:43.154: D/dalvikvm(591): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3 objects / 587632 bytes in 37ms

Comment: How to execute "adb logcat -s brief *:V|grep "pid"" command in android programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Most official Android builds do not come with grep (Edit: more recent releases now do)

You can install busybox if you want extra commands - without root you would have to put it in an alternate location.

You have the additional problem that you are trying to exec() a shell command to connect two programs via pipes, which isn't going to work unless you exec a shell interpreter and give it that command.  Or you could set up the pipe yourself and exec both programs.

But since you are writing a program, it would probably be simpler to do your pattern matching in the java code.